# jquery - rearranging elements on a page using dropzones?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, drag-and-drop

Anybody come across a good plugin or code to allow you to rearrange elements on a page using drap and drop and dropzones?

iGoogle and windows live does similar things....

Be nice to be able to drag and drop and close an element - add new elements..

And persisting this somewhere,  i presume in cookies or an external db?

I took a look on the jquery UI stuff and its got potential but it would be nice to leave a dotted line of the actually element in its original position while dragging so you can see where you was etc

Anyone come across something like this?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[jQuery UI Sortable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/)

[Docking Boxes](http://brothercake.com/site/resources/scripts/dbx/)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [JQuery UI Draggables](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/) plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I use http://www.dropzonejs.com to handle the file uploading. You can add in other drag and drop tools for the web page elements as others have mentioned.
I am using [DropZoneJS](http://www.dropzonejs.com) with [SlickGrid](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki) and some enhancements of my own to support dragging of items from other web pages to build data grids from all sorts of sources.